Can I display a number field (total seconds) as minutes and seconds in a flexipage?
Can I display a number field (total seconds) as minutes and seconds in a flexipage?   Or, do I need 2 fields in my object, one for the total seconds number field and another for a formula field that uses the total seconds to create the minutes/seconds value that is displayed in the flexipage?  I don't see how to format a field in a flexipage so I think I need a formula field.  I would appreciate any advice.  Thanks.

You'll need that formula field unless you create a custom LWC for presenting the value in [HH:]MM:SS format, or you embed a screen flow into your page that uses a formula to change the field value into the required format and presents this in a Display Text component.
